# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function throws errors when parse the obsolete enum properties

Tags: c#, enums, json.net, deserialization, obsolete

I want to mark my existing Enum property as obsolete and add the new one for same functionality. So, two enums (new one and obsolete marked one) available in my project.

While using the jsonconvert.deserializeobject function to serialize this enums value throws the below errors only from the Newtonsoft 11.0 above version.

`InvalidOperationException: Enum name 'stringedit' already exists on enum 'EditingType'. 
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.EnumUtils.InitializeValuesAndNames(Type enumType) JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "boolean" to type 'Student.Models.EditingType'. Path 'columns[0].editType', line 1, position 3997. Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)`

If there is any changes need to do in my project or if there is any plan to resolve this new error from serialization function.

I have used the below code block for my obsolete enum property serialization.

```
[DataContract]

public enum EditingType

{

    [Obsolete("String property has been deprecated. Use StringEdit property instead")]

    [EnumMember(Value = "stringedit")]

    String,

    [EnumMember(Value = "stringedit")]

    StringEdit

}

public class JsonPropertyAttribute : Attribute

{
    public JsonPropertyAttribute(string argName)
    {
        PropertyName = argName;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class JsonConverterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ConverterType
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string ValueType
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public JsonConverterAttribute(Type type, string valueType)
    {
        this.ConverterType = type;
        this.ValueType = valueType;
    }
    public JsonConverterAttribute(Type type)
    {
        this.ConverterType = type;

    }

}

public abstract class Converter
{
    protected internal abstract IDictionary<string, object> BuildJsonDictionary(object value);

    public abstract string SerializeToJson(object inputObject);
}
public class StringEnumConverter : Converter
{
    protected internal override IDictionary<string, object> BuildJsonDictionary(object value)
    {

        IDictionary<string, object> jsonDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Type objectType = value.GetType();

        FieldInfo member = objectType.GetField(value.ToString(), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        var attrList = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true);
        var enumMember = attrList.OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        string val = enumMember != null ? enumMember.Value : value.ToString();

        jsonDictionary.Add(value.GetType().Name, val);

        return jsonDictionary;
    }


    public override string SerializeToJson(object inputObject)
    {
        var attrList = inputObject.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false);
        var listAttr = attrList.ToList();
        FlagsAttribute flagAttr = attrList.Count() != 0 ? (FlagsAttribute)listAttr.Find(item => item.GetType() == typeof(FlagsAttribute)) : null;
        bool flag = (flagAttr != null) ? true : false;
        if (flag)
        {
            int value = (int)inputObject;
            return value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> enumDictionary = BuildJsonDictionary(inputObject);
            object enumValue = enumDictionary.First().Value;
            string enumstring = "\"" + enumValue.ToString() + "\"";
            return enumstring;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    private EditingType _editingType = EditingType.StringEdit;

    [JsonProperty("editType")]
    [DefaultValue(EditingType.StringEdit)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public EditingType EditType
    {
        get { return _editingType; }
        set { _editingType = value; }
    }
}
```

> The below deserialize function will throws the error in latest NewtonSoft.json (from 11.X version)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       // This function will throws the error
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"editType\":\"string\"}", typeof(TestClass));
        return View();
    }
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Identical-sounding Newtonsoft issue on GitHub: [Issue  #1788: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function throws errors when pass the obsolete enum properties](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1788).

Answer (score 0):

> I looked into this and it is expected behavior. Json.NET now always cares about EnumMember and you have duplicate values.
>
> Implement a JsonConverter if you want to customize its serialization. I don't know what you're trying to do with the conversion classes in your sample but Json.NET doesn't care about them.

[Quoting Json.NET's author](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1788#issuecomment-433592654) from @dbc's GitHub link